# Snowflake auto scaling and concurrency

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a medium snowflake warehouse with below conf.

min cluster :1
max cluster : 6
Max concurrency level : 12

I am running 100 parallel queries from 100 sessions ( 1 session 1 query). With 100 queries on moderate data set is taking max 21 seconds to process all the queries. Most of the queries are having more than 90% time as queuing time. Even we have 6 max clusters , snowflake is adding only 2 clusters for all the workload. I am pretty confused as i was expecting all the clusters to be active instead of having more queuing time with 2 clusters. Can you please help me here and let me know you experiences on auto scaling.

Comment: What type of statements are you executing and what is your scaling policy set to?  Also, why did you modify the max concurrency level?  This is not a recommended modification from the default, so curious as to the use-case.

Comment: Also, I suspect that what you are seeing is that Snowflake is determining that the queue time of each query is small enough that it doesn't warrant spinning up another cluster to handle it, since there is some analysis happening behind the scenes and there is some overheard to spinning up a cluster.  How long does it take to execute the 100 queries if you set your warehouse to MIN: 6, MAX: 6?

Comment: 21 seconds sounds good. I am sure the auto cluster resize was a every minute or two type thing.. 21s is not really loaded.. We run a number of warehouses doing 300K queries a day, and those scale the cluster size nicely when the queue builds up.. So if you know you are going to run many queries in parallel, for a short time manually spin the cluster bigger and then resize it down after..